# Space between column in RadGridView in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, telerik

I am showing columns dynamically in Radgridview using c#.

```
    private void chk_Click(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox ChkBox = ((System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)e.OriginalSource);
        string ControlName = ChkBox.Name.Substring(4);
        if (ChkBox.IsChecked == true)
        {

            VReportViewer.GrdReport.Columns[ControlName].IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {

            VReportViewer.GrdReport.Columns[ControlName].IsVisible = false;
        }
        return;
    }
```

But when i click check box ..columns are showing.But in Between column i am getting space.

Let me know how i solve this.

..[image: Please See the screen shot]

Comment: Just a suggestion, rather than an answer, as I've not seen this error myself using the similar `RadGrid` control. I am aware of another attribute available on `RadGrid` called `Display`, there are slight differences in the way each works, maybe changing the `.IsVisible = false` to `.Display = false` will solve your problem.

Comment: Is there a defined style template for this PART of the control? That's where I'd look.